# Composer will not install my newest tag, but one version older, always

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I recently added a package to composer with correct tags and all stuff that needs to make it work. Whenever I try to require this package or update an installation it won't install my earliest tag, but exactly one older.

The package can be found here: https://packagist.org/packages/gumnet/magento-2-automatic-cancel-pending-orders

For now I made a workaround always creating one more tag after an update and clients get the updated code, but that's not the best option.

Anyone can help me with that ?

Thanks !

Comment: How long did you wait between releasing the tag and requiring it? Packagist shows the update on the website after some seconds, but it takes some minutes till this is available for usage

Answer (score 0):

Nico Haase you are right !

I am adding a response just to close the answer. I could not install the newest version because I did not give enough time to composer be fully updated. After some minutes it works fine.

Comment: I got someone editing my answer removing part of my text, maybe with pure intention to get points on the system. Please do not !